Excluding some values from the quintile classification in QGIS
I am working in QGIS with a vector layer of about 8000 records and I would like to use the graduate symbology, equal count (quantile, 5 classes) with a variable that contains some records to which the value 888888 is associated with missing data (these are about 3-4 cases).
How can I exclude these records from the quintile classification?

Query out the data you do not want to see.  In the Layer Properties choose Source.  Then choose Query Builder.  Query out those values that you do not want before assigning symbology.

Here I have queried out two of my data values.  In English that might read "don't show records where the UpdateYR value is 1999 and don't show records where the UpdateYR is 2024".

And here is the resulting symbology with no 1999 or no 2024 values.


Hello, this solutin is partially good because it eliminates at all the data from the dataset (there are holes in the map). I would like still to insert in the legend these data (writing "missing values", but separating them from the quintile classification.

You should submit that as a separate question.
